# How to Build a Model with Correlation / Statistical Dependency for Bayesian A / B Testing

Tags: bayesian, ab-test, decision-theory, pymc

I use the Beta Binomial model for A/B testing.

I wonder if there a way to build a model in `PyMC` which models correlation between the conversion rate of group A with B.
Are there some classic ways to build the prior in such manner?

Comment: Related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441924.